# In Hilbert space: $x_n → x$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ weakly and $\Vert x_n \Vert → \Vert x \Vert$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

> Assume that $H$ is a $\mathbb K$-Hilbert space, $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ a sequence in $H$ and $x ∈ H$.
>   Show that $x_n → x$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ weakly and $\Vert x_n \Vert → \Vert x \Vert$.

I'm trying to prove this statement. 
The $\Rightarrow$ is basically clear, since a  strongly convergent sequence is also weakly convergent. But how can I show the other direction $\Leftarrow$ ?

Comment: hint: $\langle x_n - x, x_n - x \rangle = \dotsb \to 0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show that $x_n\to x$, you must show that $||x_n-x||\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $x_n\to x$ weakly, we know that
$$\langle x_n,y\rangle \to \langle x,y\rangle$$
for all $y\in H$, so in particular $\langle x_n,x\rangle\to\langle x,x\rangle$. Hence
$$\langle x,x_n\rangle=\overline{\langle x_n,x\rangle}\to\overline{\langle x,x\rangle}=\langle x,x\rangle$$
as well.

Therefore
$$ ||x_n-x||^2=\langle x_n-x,x_n-x\rangle=||x_n||^2-\langle x_n,x\rangle-\langle x,x_n\rangle +||x||^2\to 2||x||^2-2\langle x,x\rangle=0$$
so $x_n\to x$.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick anwer. Is it most of the times the same way of "proof method" to show such statements? Basically, playing around with the inner product properties and the limit?

Comment: Generally looking at the square of the norm is useful whenever the norm comes from an inner product.

Comment: Okay, great! Thanks for your help!