# Convergence of sequences in Hilbert spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

In a Hilbert space, let a sequence $(x_n)$ be weakly convergent to $x$ and be satisfied $\|x_{n+1}-x_n\|\to 0.$ I wonder if we can deduce that $(x_n)$ strongly converges to $x$, or at least it contains a subsequence strongly converges to $x$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. In $\ell^2$, you can consider the following sequence:
$$
e_1,
\frac12 e_2,
e_2,
\frac12 e_2,
\frac13 e_3,
\frac23 e_3,
e_3,
\frac23 e_3,
\frac13 e_3,
\frac14 e_4,
\frac24 e_4,
\frac34 e_4,
e_4,
\frac34 e_4,
\frac24 e_4,
\frac14 e_4,
\ldots$$
It is easy to check that this sequence has all desired properties.

Now, without a convergent subsequence:
$$
e_1, e_1 + \frac12 e_2,
e_1 + e_2,
\frac12 e_1 + e_2,
e_2,
e_2 + \frac13 e_3,
e_2 + \frac23 e_3,
e_2 + e_3,
\frac23 e_2 + e_3,
\frac13 e_2 + e_3,
e_3,
\ldots
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So the sequence may not converge, however in your counterexample it still contains a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @KTU: Now I have written down a similar sequence without a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Very nice example +1

Comment: @grew: very clear and interesting example. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited heavily** using [In Hilbert space: $x_n → x$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ weakly and $\Vert x_n \Vert → \Vert x \Vert$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027861/in-hilbert-space-x-n-%E2%86%92-x-if-and-only-if-x-n-to-x-weakly-and-vert-x-n-ve?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the fact that weak convergence is unique:  If $$||x_{n+1}-x_n|| $$ converges to zero, then $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in H. So, $x_n$ converges to some $y$ in H. Using the other post, we have that $x_n$ converges weakly to $y$. But, weak convergence is unique. So, $x=y$ implying that $x_n$ converges to $x$ in H. Thus, $||x-x_n||$ tends to zero trivially giving us strong convergence.

Comment: earlier post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027861/in-hilbert-space-x-n-%E2%86%92-x-if-and-only-if-x-n-to-x-weakly-and-vert-x-n-ve?rq=1

Comment: I don't see how you obtain the inequality $\|x-x_n\| \leq \|x-x_m\|$.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem, I dropped a limit. We had that $||x-x_n|| = ||x-x_{n+1} +x_{n+1} -x_n||  \leq  ||x-x_{n+1}|| +||x_{n+1}-x_n||$ I took a limit and disregarded later.

Comment: You still haven't said anything. I don't see how your inequality helps with your claim.

Comment: Jacky, I think I fixed the proof

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, $(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence  with just the property $\|x_{n+1}-x_n\|\to 0$. So the proof should be revised.