# Strong convergence from weak one. Correct reasoning?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I have obtained a Palais-Smale sequence $x_n$ for a functional $I:H^1(\mathbb{T}^2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (where $\mathbb{T}^2$ is a two dimensional torus), i.e. $I(x_n)\rightarrow c$ and $I'(x_n)\rightarrow 0$. This sequence is weakly convergent to some point $x\in X$. I **want to prove that is strongly convergent**. In order to do that, I just need the convergence of the norm, $\Vert x_n\Vert_{H^1}\rightarrow \Vert x\Vert_{H^1}$, in view of  [In Hilbert space: $x_n → x$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ weakly and $\Vert x_n \Vert → \Vert x \Vert$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027861/in-hilbert-space-x-n-%e2%86%92-x-if-and-only-if-x-n-to-x-weakly-and-vert-x-n-ve)  . I want to know if my reasoning is correct:

Since $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in $H^1$, $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in $L^2$ and by Rellich-Kondrachov theorem, $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $L^2$ (up to a subsequence that we assume is the same). Similarly, $\nabla x_n\rightarrow\nabla x$ in $L^2$. Therefore, $\Vert x_n\Vert_{L^2}\rightarrow \Vert x\Vert_{L^2}$ and $\Vert \nabla x_n\Vert_{L^2}\rightarrow \Vert \nabla x\Vert_{L^2}$, which implies that $\Vert x_n\Vert_{H^1}\rightarrow \Vert x\Vert_{H^1}$. **Is my reasoning correct?**
Any comment is welcome! Thank you.

Comment: How do you infer $\nabla x_n \to \nabla x$ in $L^2$? "Similarly" does not work.

Comment: Since $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ in $H^1$, it follows that $\nabla x_n$ converges weakly to $\nabla x$ in $L^2$ and then apply Reillich... Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. Rellich says that $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ in $H^1$ implies $x_n \to x$ in $L^2$. If you want to have $\nabla x_n \to \nabla x$ in $L^2$, you need $\nabla x \rightharpoonup \nabla x$ in $H^1$.

Comment: I thought that weak convergence in $H^1$ implies weak convergence in $L^2$ and also weak convergence of the gradient in $L^2$... Any idea to show then what I want??

Comment: Yes, it implies weak convergence of the gradient in $L^2$ but not weak convergence of the gradient in $H^1$. So weak convergence in $H^1$ does not imply strong convergence in $H^1$ without further properties of the sequence. Maybe a "Palais-Smale sequence" has some further spetial properties, but I do not know this notion.

Comment: I see now... thank you for your answer!