# prove a subset of a given Hilbert space $X$ is convergent in norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Assume $\{x,x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ is a subset of a given Hilbert space $X$ with norm $||\cdot||$ such that $x_j$ converges to $x$ weakly and $||x_j||$ converges to $||x||$. Prove that $x_j$ converges to $x$ in norm.

For this question, I think that since $X$ is a Hilbert space, then $||x||$ is equal to the root of the inner product $\langle x,x\rangle$, $||x_j||$ is equal to the root of $\langle x_j,x_j\rangle$, so the root of $\langle x_j,x_j\rangle$ converges to root of $\langle x,x\rangle$.  Does this mean $\langle x_j,x_j\rangle$ converges to $\langle x,x\rangle$?

For my main question, I hope to get a counterexample if $\{x,x1,x2,\ldots\}$ is a subset of a Banach space. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027861/in-hilbert-space-x-n-%e2%86%92-x-if-and-only-if-x-n-to-x-weakly-and-vert-x-n-ve

Comment: @carmichael561 Thank you so much, i get the idea, may i get a counterexample for Banach space?